# How to Derive a Signing Key for Signature Version 4 (AWS) for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, aws-lambda, http-status-code-403

How to Derive a Signing Key for Signature Version 4 (AWS) for Google Apps Script

```
function invokeLambda() {
  // Credenciales de AWS
  var accessKey = 'KEY_TEST';
  var secretKey = 'KEY_TEST';
  var region = 'us-east-1';
  var service = 'lambda';

  // Fecha y hora actual en formato ISO 8601
  var now = new Date();
  var amzDate = now.toISOString().split('.')[0] + 'Z';




  // Payload de la solicitud
  var payload = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };

  // Convertir el payload a una cadena JSON
  var payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);

  // Calcular el hash SHA-256 del payload
  var sha256 = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, payloadString);
  var payloadHash = Utilities.base64Encode(sha256);

  // Crear la cadena de autenticación
  var canonicalRequest = 'POST\n/2015-03-31/functions/your-function-name/invocations\n\ncontent-type:application/json\nhost:lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:' + amzDate + '\n\ncontent-type;host;x-amz-date\n' + payloadHash;
  var canonicalRequestHash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, canonicalRequest);
  var canonicalRequestHashString = Utilities.base64Encode(canonicalRequestHash);
  var stringToSign = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n' + amzDate + '\n' + now.toISOString().substr(0, 8) + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/aws4_request\n' + canonicalRequestHashString;

  // Convertir la clave secreta y los datos en arreglos de bytes
  var secretBytes = Utilities.newBlob(secretKey).getBytes();
  var dateBytes = Utilities.newBlob(now.toISOString().substr(0, 8)).getBytes();

  // Firmar la región utilizando la clave secreta y la fecha
  var dateRegionKey = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(dateBytes, secretBytes);




  var serviceBytes = Utilities.newBlob(service).getBytes();
  var dateRegionServiceKey = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(serviceBytes, dateRegionKey);

  // Convertir la cadena en un arreglo de bytes
  var stringToSignBytes = stringToBytes(stringToSign);

  // Firmar la cadena
  var signingKey = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(stringToSignBytes, dateRegionServiceKey);

  // Convertir la cadena en un arreglo de bytes
  // Convertir la cadena en un arreglo de bytes
  var stringToSignBytes = Utilities.newBlob(stringToSign).getBytes();
  var signingKeyBytes = Utilities.newBlob(signingKey).getBytes();


  // Crear una instancia de la clase Utilities.DigestHmacSha256
  var hmacSha256 = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, signingKeyBytes);


  // Firmar la cadena
  var signatureBytes = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(stringToSignBytes, signingKeyBytes);


  // Convertir la firma en una cadena hexadecimal
  var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(signatureBytes);


  // Encabezados de la solicitud
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Amz-Date': amzDate,
    'X-Amz-Security-Token': '',
    'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + accessKey + '/' + now.toISOString().substr(0, 8) + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=' + signature
  };

  // Opciones de la solicitud
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': payloadString
  };

  // URL de la función Lambda
  var url = 'https://lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/';

  // Realizar la solicitud HTTP
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(responseText);
}

function stringToBytes(s) {
  var bytes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    bytes.push(s.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

I have something like this but it doesn't work for me. I get error:
Exception: Request failed for https://lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws returned code 403. Truncated server response: {"message":"Date in Credential scope does not match YYYYMMDD from ISO-8601 version of date from HTTP. "} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: Can you provide the official document of `How to Derive a Signing Key for Signature Version 4 (AWS)` you want to use?

Comment: Yes, this was the one I used, I adapted it a little because I needed to send headers:
https://github.com/dxdc/aws-sdk-google-apps/tree/master